# What are "schlieren" in English?

Tags: word-choice

The German word for these patterns is "Schliere, pl. Schlieren", and apparently this word has entered the English language as a loanword (cf. article [Schlieren](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schlieren) in Wikipedia or entry [schliere](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/172430) in OED). But the German loanword is probably not something most native speakers of English understand without the help of a dictionary, so what would you call, or how would you describe, the following patterns?

Concrete:

[image: concrete surface]

Air:

[image: Schlieren photograph of air rising from a candle]

Oil on water:

[image: oil mixing with water]

Coffee and milk:

[image: cream being poured into a cup of coffee]

Paint:

[image: liquid paints mixing]

Smoke:

[image: plume of smoke]

Rock:

[image: striated rock surface]

Marbled paper:

[image: marbled paper]

And so on.

---

"Waves" is not applicable, because waves are vertical undulations of the surface, while these are a pattern on, or *inside*, the surface level, with no amplitude.

"Striæ" does not really fit either, because those refer more to the parallel layers, than to the curly forms.

Comment: Pretty sure there's no word for that in English. Those patterns (with the exception of rock which is created by minerals) are due to turbulence.

Comment: But if there is no word, English speakers can still *describe* such a pattern. It is such a common everyday occurrence, that there *must* be a way to refer to it. Just think: How would you talk about the pattern of oil on water? Or of the pattern that you aim for when you marble paper?

Comment: @What, we'd usually just say 'patterns'. Each of them might have specific names e.g. 'Latte art', but there's no overall term.

Comment: @what there are adjectives we could use, but none of them would be specific to those patterns, nor would they be the only words possible. My first thoughts for those were such as swirls for the oil painting, or veins for the rock. But somebody could just as easily use lines or ripples or waves etc.

Comment: what, if that word has entered English, it's certainly not common. This is the first that I've heard of it.

Comment: @Moogle Just noted that you proposed "swirls" in your comment before Andrew Leach posted the answer I accepted. Sorry for overlooking that.

Comment: @what: Don't worry - an answer should be under answers, not under comments. You can't accept a comment as the right answer.

Comment: Most of these patterns are 'schlieren-like', but only your air example is a schlieren pattern. The wikipedia article is pretty clear about what schlieren patterns are. The others I would describe as vortex shedding,  striated veins of white stone, and marbling.

Comment: Just to second @BobbiBennett, the word schlieren in English is very clearly defined to be the optical distortion due to variations in a transparent medium. Only the air cases you gave are actual schlieren images. The rest are not optical distortions nor are they transparent.

Comment: In English I associate this word with the flame image created by the well-known **Schlieren optical system**. The others are just swirls.

Comment: @BobbiBennett, tpg2114, SpehroPefhany I understand that the meaning of the English word "schlieren" is limited to what Wikipedia explains. I am looking for a word for the general pattern, irrespective of the medium and cause. Which is why I gave a wide range of visual examples.

Comment: @what I notice you just put a 300 bounty on your question. Are you hoping for a newer better answer? 'swirl' or 'streak' are the exact English words to describe this. 'schlieren' is entirely new to me in English and would not be understood.

Comment: @Mitch I just want to make a gift of my reputation to someone before I delete my account here.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

A descriptive term for the patterns you illustrate is ***swirl***:

> A twisting or spiralling movement or pattern:
>   *she emerged with a swirl of skirts*
>   *swirls of colour*
>
> [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/swirl)

> **1a :**  a whirling mass or motion :  **eddy**
>   **b :**  whirling confusion <a *swirl* of events>
>   **2 :**  a twisting shape, mark, or pattern
>   **3 :**  an act or instance of swirling
>
> [Merriam-Webster.com](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/swirl)

Comment: Since the pattern I'm describing is in fact moving, this is a perfect fit. Thank you!

Comment: I would also add marbled, though that really only makes sense for hard surfaces such as the concrete and rock examples.

Answer (score 13):

Technically speaking, the phenomenon that causes that pattern in fluids like water or smoke is *turbulence*, in which you'll find terms like **vortex** (plural **vortices**), which has connotations of speed or violence, or **eddy**, which is more or less the same as far as fluid dynamics is concerned, but in terms of literary connotations is somewhat calmer and/or slower. Both of these terms imply motion, though, so they might not work so well when talking about rock or wood.

In general, when describing that pattern I would probably go with **whorl**, which is also used to refer to the looping pattern in fingerprints, or maybe **swirl**.

Answer (score 8):

If you take a direct translation, the English would be **streak**, or **streaks**.

With that said, in English the different types of patterning often attract different names. 'Lines' of streaking is often referred to as **grain**, rounded streaking is sometimes referred to as **marbling**

**Marbling:**

> having markings or coloration suggestive of marble
>   <sup>[source](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/marbled)</sup>

*Could apply to: paint, oil, coffee, marbled paper*

**Grain:**

> the arrangement, pattern, or direction of fibres in substances such as
>   wood, stone, cloth, or paper
>   <sup>[source](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/grain)</sup>

*Could apply to: concrete, rock*

A word for the smoke like pattern is a bit more tricky, perhaps; **smoky, wispy or diffuse**.

Effectively, what you are seeing are **patterns in nature**

> Patterns in nature are visible regularities of form found in the
>   natural world. These patterns recur in different contexts and can
>   sometimes be modelled mathematically. Natural patterns include
>   symmetries, trees, spirals, meanders, waves, foams, arrays, cracks and
>   stripes.<sup>[source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patterns_in_nature)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Americans use [Schlieren Systems](http://www.edmundoptics.com/testing-targets/testing-alignment/schlieren-systems/1655) to do [Schlieren photography](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schlieren_photography) The techniques go back to the 1800's, but [except in France, there's no real alternative](http://books.google.com/books?id=HWtB2R0gWFgC&pg=PA7&dq=schlieren%20foucault&hl=en&sa=X&ei=gNPsU56vLIiAygS4poDQAw&ved=0CB4Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=schlieren%20foucault&f=false) to the word Schlieren.

Comment: Well, that beats a bunch of baffling downvotes. Thanks.